# Smooth roc object multiple iterations Error is.unsorted(roc$specificities)

Tags: r, r-caret, smoothing, roc, auc

- Ran `sbf()` from caret package (for 100 iterations)
- Computed ROC value
- Plot ROC (As they are stair steps), need to smooth 100 roc objects.

For smoothing an ROC object, tried 10 iterations
The function created checks if there are more than 1 finite value rows in data frame of sp, se. If there are more than 1 row with finite values, the smoothing of roc object happens, else it returns the same roc object as it is without smoothing. 
10 iterations runs successfully sometimes, some being smooth roc objects and others roc object. 
But when I run 10 iterations again, the following error comes

`Error in if (is.unsorted(roc$specificities)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Have checked the **smooth.roc.binormal** function. I see that there is qnorm() function being used and that how many rows are there with finite values in dataframe of sp and se.

I am not sure where the above error occurs or at what step the `is.unsorted(roc$specificities)` is checked.

Presently, I have 100 roc objects with me as a list. The function may result in few smoothed roc objects and others being roc object itself as it is.

**Expected Output for 100 iterations**

[image]

Where should I check the above error in my function, as it stops the process of smoothing/non smoothing of roc object.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/333599 otherwise it's going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Will try to post a reproducible example.